# Add 'Selected' Attribute to Dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add the 'selected' attribute to a dropdown in React. Basically, we are creating an array of React elements that then gets rendered later in the script, here is the idea:

```
for (var i = daysInMonth; i > 0; --i) {
    rows.push(_react2['default'].createElement(
      _reactBootstrap.MenuItem,
      { eventKey: i, onSelect: this.updateBoardWeek.bind(this) },
      'Week ',
      i
    ));
}
```

Basically on the first loop through, I want the option/menu item to have a 'selected' attribute on it. I can't seem to find that specific attribute/a way to add that to the first item in the loop.

The documentation I've seen on it here:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#menu-items

Doesn't seem to show any support for attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between an option and a menu item. I don't think menu items are supposed to be selectable.

Comment: The 'MenuItem' though seems to render a dropdown 'option' tag. What's the difference between an option and menu item then?